# Where should one post questions about numerical analysis?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Someone on another Stack Exchange site wants to integrate a function for which there seems to be no closed-form anti-derivative. One approach is to fit a function with more amenable properties to the given function. One question would be which class of functions would be best to fit.

Where would one post questions like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has some questions about [numerical methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods), but their [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions another solution:

> There are certain subjects that, while still on-topic here, might be better addressed by one of our sister sites:
>
> ...
>
> - Numerical analysis and scientific computing: [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

You can browse [numerical analysis](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) questions to get a feeling of what details should be included in order to make the question well-received.